# Find a Lagrange multipliers problem on a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$ which proves the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

> Find a Lagrange multipliers problem on a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$ which proves the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means: $$ (x^1 \cdot x^2 \cdot \cdot \cdot x^d)^{\frac{1}{d}} \leq \frac{x^1+...+x^d}{d}$$

My idea was:

Let $y^1, ..., y^d \in \mathbb{R}$.

And the sphere which contains the point defined by them $S = \left \{ \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d : g(\vec{x})=||\vec{x}|| = ||(y^1, ..., y^d)||=n \right \} $.

And the function $f(x^1, ..., x^d) = x^1 \cdot \cdot \cdot x^d - (\frac{x^1+...+x^d}{d})^d$.

If we can show that $f \leq 0$ that would suffice.

But when I tried solving the equations we get from $\nabla f(\vec{x}) = \lambda \nabla g(\vec{x}), g(\vec{x}) = n$ I couldn't find a way to express the ext points, though we know they exists since $S$ is compact and $f$ is continuous.

Should I approach this in a different manner, or am I just missing how to solve these equations?

Note: there are some similar questions on the site but as far as I could find their instructions are at least somewhat different, so please make sure before offering to close this question.

Comment: Do you have a typo in the statement of the inequality? Homogeneity is all wrong.

Comment: My suggestion would be to look for constrained critical point(s) of the two functions $f(x)=(x^1\dots x^d)^{1/d}$ and $g(x)=x^1+\dots+x^d$ subject to the constraint $\|x\|=1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, fixed. I'll think about your suggestion.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not sure how this helps actually. The critical points don't tell us anything about the relationship between the two functions as far as I can tell.

Comment: You're right. The constrained critical points are the same, but both are maxima. I don't see what your professor had in mind. The usual approach, which I'm sure you discarded, is to maximize $f$ subject to $g=\text{const}$.